# Correct database structure for message table

Tags: json, database, data-structures, firebase

I'm trying to write a messaging app using PhoneGap, AngularJS and Firebase. I'm trying to work out what the correct the correct database structure should be given Firebase unusual query methods ([1](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html), [2](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-01-02-queries-part-two.html)).

I need a messages 'table' where all messages are stored, however the issue is that this is a NoSQL table, so it's quite hard to retrieve data if it's not formatted specifically.

For example, I originally considered something like `/messages/{userId}` to get all messages for a user, and `/messages/{userId}/{partnerId}` to get a specific message chain, but I can't do that because it would mean that data has to be duplicated, once for the person sending the message and once for the person receiving.

Can anyone suggest a layout which would work well with Firebase's query structure, and allows:

1. Retrieval of all messages to/from a user
2. Retrieval of a specific thread from one user to another

Comment: Maybe I am stating the obvious here but shouldn't you just simply use: `/{chatId}/messages`?

Comment: Duplicating data is quite common in Firebase, so that alone is not a reason to discard your original consideration. https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html. It is a simple model and would for example allow you to easily secure every {userId} branch to only that specific user.

Comment: @Sander_P The issue is that chat threads are not assigned an ID. Rather than structuring based on conversations, one of the important points in the app is that chats are structured by users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look in this post about [data denormalizing](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html) . I faced a similar challenge and the solution which worked for me was storing all data under auto ID in specific object and if needed I stored a reference to that data in as many places as required.

Applying this to your problem, if simplified, I would go for something like this:

```
root/messages/{message_by_auto_id}/{message_body}

root/users/{user_id}/messages_this_user_can_see/{ref_to_message}
```

so If a user posts a message the app needs to save the message in messages and save the reference to that message to each friend as above.

Comment: Wow, that actually makes a lot of sense, can't believe I did't think of this.